# value class type of flink mapstate

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I would like to declare a flink mapState as below which value type is a pojo arraylist, what should I set its value class type?

```
private transient MapState<String, List<pojo>> mapState;
mapState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(
                new MapStateDescriptor<String, List<pojo>>(
                        "RIGHT_BUFFER",
                        String.class,
                        ???
                )
        );
```

it's not okay when I set value type to `pojo.class` or `List.class`. how to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
private final MapStateDescriptor<String, List<Pojo>> mapStateDesc =
    new MapStateDescriptor<>(
        "RIGHT_BUFFER",
        BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
        new ListTypeInfo<>(Pojo.class));
```

Comment: I knew I shouldn't have wasted time formatting my answer :) And now I know about `ListTypeInfo`...

Comment: Your answer is probably more helpful, since it will work for any generic type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `TypeInformation` with `TypeHint` to handle generic classes. Something like:

```java
        mapState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(
                        new MapStateDescriptor<String, List<pojo>>(
                                "RIGHT_BUFFER",
                                TypeInformation.of(String.class),
                                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<List<pojo>>() {})
                        )
                );
```